# Integrate UIView to cocos2d: how to release UIView elements?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiview, cocos2d-iphone

If I add a UITextField to the openGLView and remove it again, dealloc is never called.

```
// add a textfield to the openGLView
codeTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:codeTextfieldFrame];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:codeTextfield];

// remove the textfield
[codeTextfield removeFromSuperview];

// call replaceScene
[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Menu node]];

// dealloc will not be called
```

I suffer with this problem a long time and there is no solution in sight.

Comment: release it after you add it as a subview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the retain counts along the way; this should help you to see what's going on.

```
codeTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:codeTextfieldFrame];
// RETAIN COUNT IS NOW 1
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:codeTextfield];
// RETAIN COUNT IS NOW 2

[codeTextfield removeFromSuperview];
// RETAIN COUNT IS NOW 1
```

To get the count back to 0 after removing `codeTextfield` from the view, instead do this:

```
codeTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:codeTextfieldFrame];
// RETAIN COUNT IS NOW 1
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:codeTextfield];
// RETAIN COUNT IS NOW 2
[codeTextfield release];
// RETAIN COUNT IS NOW 1

[codeTextfield removeFromSuperview];
// RETAIN COUNT IS NOW 0 -- DEALLOC WILL BE CALLED
```

Answer (score 1):

`addSubview` retains the view.  As you created the object with `alloc`, you own it too.  Removing the view will only decrease the retain count by 1.  You want `[codeTextfield release]` after you add it as a subview.